# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } In Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On onMouseOver alert shown properly but when onMouseOut then Exception got.I created html Dynamically.Please help me where i write wrong code.

```
$('#skillsUL').append("<li><span class='skillcount'><a class='count'>1</a><a class='skillname'>"+userObj.skillsList[cnt].skillName+"</a></span></li><div class='skillholders'><a class='endorse'></a><ul class='skillimages'><li><img src='http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_30_30/p/8/000/1b1/33d/0ef7906.jpg'></li><li class='skillarrow'><a class='arrowclick'></a></li></ul><a class='endorsepart'><span class='endorsing'>" +
                            "<span class='eplus' onMouseOver='document.getElementById(\"etext"+cnt+"\").style.display = \"block\";' onMouseOut='document.getElementById(\"etext"+cnt+"\").style.display = \"none\";'>&nbsp;</span><span class='eminus'>&nbsp;</span><span id='etext"+cnt+"' style='color: #0073B2; float: left; line-height: 27px; margin-left: 6px; margin-right: 0; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 10px; background:#FFF; font-weight:bold;display:none;'>Endorse</span>" +
                            "<span id='unetext' style='color: #0073B2; float: left; line-height: 27px; margin-left: 6px; margin-right: 0; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 10px; background:#FFF; font-weight:bold;'>Remove Endorsement</span></span><div class='skillline'><span class='liner'></span></div></a></div>");
```

Comment: @Rahul: to ask a new question, post a new question, don't edit your old ones.

Comment: Sir my Question is on hold so how can i improve my question i am new in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
onMouseOut='document.getElementById('etext').style.display = 'none';'
```

Try:

```
onMouseOut='document.getElementById("\etext\").style.display = \"none\";'
```

Comment: thanks for comment but still same exception got.

Comment: Sorry Sir Working fine...Thanks alot i forgot to write ; after none.Many Thanks..Sir i have Question about asking question